# Override Pageable findAll for selecting fewer columns in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

How to Override spring data repository to select only selected columns when going to pages that are discovered from /api page in spring data rest.

I added findAll as below -

```
public interface UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User, Integer>, UserRepositoryCustom {

    @Query("select u from User u where email = :email and password = :password")
    @Cacheable(value = "user-cache", key = "#user.login")
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public User findUserByEmailAndPassword(@Param("email") String email, @Param("password") String password);

    @RestResource(rel = "byEmail", path = "byEmail")
    public User findUserByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

    @RestResource(rel = "byPhone", path = "byPhone")
    public User findUserByPhone(@Param("phone") String phone);

     @Override 
     @Query("select u.id,u.email,u.phone from User u ")
     public Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

/api/users is giving an error -

```
{"cause":null,"message":"PersistentEntity must not be null!"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a `UserSummaryProjection` class in same package as `User`

```
@Projection(name = "summary", types = User.class)
public interface UserSummaryProjection {

    Integer getId();

    String getEmail();

}
```

Then, going at `/api/users` or `/users/3?projection=summary` gives me desired result without changing the Repository.

Answer (score -1):

Selecting subelements of User and still creating a User is somewhat counterintuitive.

I would create another entity for example **UserDetails**, that will be mapped by the same table with the same mapping.

```
public class UserDetails {
    private int uid;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
}
```

And create a Repository, based on this new Entity.